# Angularjs Apply scope change to view immediately

Tags: angularjs

How can i make angular apply the changes to the view before exiting the click method? In the following example i want the span to be visible while the confirm box is shown.

```
$scope.click = function () {
    $scope.saving = true; //Not enough

    $scope.$apply(function () {
        $scope.saving = true;
    });//Throws error but works [$rootScope:inprog] $apply already in progress 
    confirm('Are you sure?');

    $scope.saving = false;
}


<span ng-show="saving">Loading ... </span>
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/TTKp4cgWXSRZfzRHzayp?p=preview)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you want to do is doing part of your code in one digest cycle of Angular and the rest in another. I accomplish this by using a small timeout:

```
$scope.click = function () {
    $scope.saving = true;

    $timeout(function() {
        confirm('Are you sure?');
        $scope.saving = false;
    }, 50);
}
```

NB: Don't forget to add `$timeout` to the dependencies of your controller